# How to prevent use of trait methods out of "use" scope in PHP

Tags: php, traits

**I'd like to know if there is any way to prevent the use of trait methods out of any class context in PHP ?**

Let me explain what I want with a short example, here is my current code :

```
// File : MyFunctions.php
trait MyFunctions {

    function hello_world() {
        echo 'Hello World !';
    }

}

// File : A.php
include 'MyFunctions.php';

class A {

    use MyFunctions;

}

// File : testTraits.php
include 'A.php';

hello_world(); // Call to undefined function -> OK, expected
A::hello_world(); // Hello World ! -> OK, expected
MyFunctions::hello_world(); // Hello World ! -> Maybe OK, but not expected, I'd like to prevent it
```

PHP manual page about traits is very comprehensive, and a lot of cases are treated, but not this one (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)

I desperatly tried to remove "static" and use "public", "protected", "private", but of course, it just didn't work. I've no other ideas so far, so maybe I'm missing something, or it's just impossible ?

Comment: I'd say it's impossible.

Comment: Why would one write a static function in a trait in the first place?

Comment: @nietonfir It was just a copy / paste from another piece of code for the example, nevermind.

Comment: [This comment](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php#109448) on the documentation page says that trait methods can always be called as if they were defined as static methods.

Comment: @ClémentMalet Maybe I don't understand your question but setting the function to `private` works for me, it is no longer available outside the class scope. Is this not the behavior you are after?

Comment: @Barmar In fact, it's that comment who led me to think about it, and I hoped there could be a workaround, but I guess there is no point to bypass this behavior, so as you said, it can ALWAYS be called

Comment: @LifeQuery Setting the method as private prevents `Trait::function();`, but it also prevents `ClassWithTrait::function();`, which is not desired.

Comment: Can you make it private in the trait, then use `use Trait { hello_world as public hello_world; }` to make it public in `ClassWithTrait`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the visibility changing feature when using a trait:

```
trait MyFunctions {

    private function _hello_world() {
        echo 'Hello World !';
    }

}

class A {

    use MyFunctions { _hello_world as public hello_world ;}
    ...
}
```

Comment: @Barmar small typo `use` construct

Comment: Thanks. FYI, for trivial typos, you can use the **edit** link instead of commenting.

Answer (score 2):

Using traits in PHP establishes the contract that functions defined in the trait can always be called as if they were defined as static methods.

If you *really* must, you can work around that behaviour dynamically by wrapping your function with a test that determines whether there is a match between [magic constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) `__CLASS__` (the name of the class the trait is used in) and `__TRAIT__` (the name of the trait itself).

If there is a match, then the method was not used as intended and you tweak its behaviour accordingly.

So your example would become:

```
trait MyFunctions {

    function hello_world() {
        if (__CLASS__ == __TRAIT__) {
            die('Sorry');
        }
        echo 'Hello World !';
    }

}
```

Comment: Working fine, but I think Barmar's answer is much more clear on what is the intent of the workaround and what is happening. Got my upvote though !

Comment: ...and Barmar got mine ;)